# Error 29 13 in android studio

Tags: android

This is my error :

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
     Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0.
     Required by:
         Firstbook:app:unspecified
       Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0.
          Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom'.
             Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom'.
                Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

What can I do??